# Does Thailand have islands like those in "Bridget Jones: The Edge of Reason"?

Tags: thailand, islands

In the movie, you can see some islands that look like those from Vietnam or China: they come out suddenly from the water, and the bottom of them look like solid rock.

Do such islands occur in Thailand? Also, is there a term for such islands?

Comment: The geological structure is called a karst. Normally what you see are limestone karsts. A picture in the question might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen *Bridget Jones: the Edge of Reason* specifically, but karst islands in Thailand have been used in a couple of other movies. [Phang-Nga Bay](https://www.google.com/search?q=phang-nga+bay&hl=en&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=W6SWVf3YEMup-QHY6ID4BQ&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAg&biw=1258&bih=952), for example, was used in *The Man With the Golden Gun* (1974);  and [Ko Phi Phi Lee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ko_Phi_Phi_Lee) was used in the 2000 film *The Beach*.  Both of these locations are on the Andaman Sea (the southwest coast of Thailand).

Comment: You beat me to it! That's one of the most beautiful places I've ever been to.

Answer (score 3):

I originally thought the movie had made it up, but they do exist. From [10 Islands for a Perfect Trip to Thailand](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/minube/10-islands-for-a-perfect_b_4266423.html):

[image: Example of such an island]